# Embed external flash video on page

Tags: html, flash, embed

There is a video which can be found [here](http://www.brainshark.com/rsa/cybersecurity101) that I would like to embed on my page somewhere. I have not been successful downloading the flash file because I am unable to access inspect element in chrome and I also cannot figure out a way to embed the flash video file by referencing the URL above.

Does anyone know a way to either download the file or embed it?

By the way, this must support IE8 (sorry everyone :) )

Comment: I never got it to work, honestly. I ended up just using a workaround for the issue. I'll accept it though as I'm sure it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Absolute URL**: http://www.brainshark.com/brainshark/viewer/getplayer.ashx?v=201207121701

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashContent" name="flashContent"
data="/brainshark/viewer/getplayer.ashx?v=201207121701" width="100%" height="100%"
style="visibility: visible; ">
    <param name="scale" value="noscale">
    <param name="wmode" value="window">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="">
    <param name="SeamlessTabbing" value="false">
    <param name="flashvars" value="pi=119002744&amp;host=www.brainshark.com&amp;securerequest=false&amp;lng=en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6">
</object>
```

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: How did you find the absolute URL?

Comment: It was embedded in the object tag. You can't run the object without passing the flashvars, however (most likely a security hotfix).

Comment: When I do a "save as" on the link above, chrome downloads a file called "getplayer.swf" - unfortunately when I load this swf file it turns out to be a blank blue screen (the same as when I click on the link above).

Comment: You'll need to use the object tag to pass the appropriate flashvars over to the .swf file. This will run it properly.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate your help! Were you able to get this to work by downloading the above file? I tried, and I changed the data tag to link to the downloaded .swf file, but nothing shows up but a blue background. I would love to accept your answer but like I said, I haven't had any luck.